# Laravel Queue - how to run the queue sequentially without using cronjob

Tags: laravel, cron, queue

I want to use queue job to update data by time create to database

Example . i have table job_history

I will insert multiple record into job_history table by status (status = 0 not finish)

I want to handle all record with status = 0 by queue (time create ascending)

> (It mean after processing the record 1 completed (update record with status = 1 finished or timeout by 60s )
>   then automatically next to the record 2,3... until the end (update status=1)

And when i create new record into job_history table then queue always listen to continue handle with status =0

=> I can handle by cronjob (but cron job only configured at least once a minute => That interrupts the work) , 
I want to handle if record 1 finished will continue 2 ( not wating 1 minute by cronjob)

I don't know laravel queue can do this job not ?
and how to setup it ?

Answer (score 0):

In production in order tu consume queue jobs you can use supervisor.

You can read this doc : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: Thank you, but It seem the laravel queue job is asynchronous running, i want to  know  how to setup processing when the record 1 completed then automatically next to the record 2,3.. until end

Answer (score 0):

`queue:work` handles a job at a time, sequentially, as long as there are jobs to do in the queue. You don't have to do anything special to achieve what you're asking for.

Also, you don't need (strictly) a supervisor to run queues, those can be handled with a cron and a relatively simple script to check if the worker is running and launching or restarting it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can handle this situation by excuting this command:

```
queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

With the cron, it will check every minute if the queue is not empty. Then it will do all existing jobs in the queue. Then terminate.